# Modifying CMakeLists.txt in LLVM for a specific target, but no change

Tags: cmake, llvm

I'm working on a project (we call it Escala) which uses LLVM. We are using [OR1K](https://github.com/openrisc/llvm-or1k) as our starting point. There is an extra command that I added to the CMakeLists.txt but for some reason nothing happens when I run `cmake`. The file I modified was in `lib/Target/Escala/CMakeLists.txt` (this directory does not exist in `llvm-or1k`. You can think of modifying `lib/Target/OR1K/CMakeLists`

This is how the code looked before modification:

```
set(LLVM_TARGET_DEFINITIONS Escala.td)

tablegen(LLVM EscalaGenRegisterInfo.inc -gen-register-info)
tablegen(LLVM EscalaGenInstrInfo.inc -gen-instr-info)
tablegen(LLVM EscalaGenAsmWriter.inc -gen-asm-writer)
tablegen(LLVM EscalaGenAsmMatcher.inc -gen-asm-matcher)
tablegen(LLVM EscalaGenMCCodeEmitter.inc -gen-emitter -mc-emitter)
tablegen(LLVM EscalaGenDAGISel.inc -gen-dag-isel)
tablegen(LLVM EscalaGenCallingConv.inc -gen-callingconv)
tablegen(LLVM EscalaGenSubtargetInfo.inc -gen-subtarget)
tablegen(LLVM EscalaGenDisassemblerTables.inc -gen-disassembler)
tablegen(LLVM EscalaGenDFAPacketizer.inc -gen-dfa-packetizer)
add_public_tablegen_target(EscalaCommonTableGen)

add_llvm_target(EscalaCodeGen
  EscalaDelaySlotFiller.cpp
  EscalaISelDAGToDAG.cpp
  EscalaISelLowering.cpp
  EscalaInstrInfo.cpp
  EscalaFrameLowering.cpp
  EscalaMachineFunctionInfo.cpp
  EscalaRegisterInfo.cpp
  EscalaSubtarget.cpp
  EscalaTargetMachine.cpp
  EscalaSelectionDAGInfo.cpp
  EscalaAsmPrinter.cpp
  EscalaMCInstLower.cpp
  EscalaMachineScheduler.cpp
    EscalaVLIWPacketizer.cpp
  )

add_subdirectory(InstPrinter)
add_subdirectory(Disassembler)
add_subdirectory(TargetInfo)
add_subdirectory(MCTargetDesc)
add_subdirectory(AsmParser)
```

and this is how it looks now:

```
set(LLVM_TARGET_DEFINITIONS Escala.td)

tablegen(LLVM EscalaGenRegisterInfo.inc -gen-register-info)
tablegen(LLVM EscalaGenInstrInfo.inc -gen-instr-info)
tablegen(LLVM EscalaGenAsmWriter.inc -gen-asm-writer)
tablegen(LLVM EscalaGenAsmMatcher.inc -gen-asm-matcher)
tablegen(LLVM EscalaGenMCCodeEmitter.inc -gen-emitter -mc-emitter)
tablegen(LLVM EscalaGenDAGISel.inc -gen-dag-isel)
tablegen(LLVM EscalaGenCallingConv.inc -gen-callingconv)
tablegen(LLVM EscalaGenSubtargetInfo.inc -gen-subtarget)
tablegen(LLVM EscalaGenDisassemblerTables.inc -gen-disassembler)
tablegen(LLVM EscalaGenDFAPacketizer.inc -gen-dfa-packetizer)
add_public_tablegen_target(EscalaCommonTableGen)

add_llvm_target(EscalaCodeGen
  EscalaDelaySlotFiller.cpp
  EscalaISelDAGToDAG.cpp
  EscalaISelLowering.cpp
  EscalaInstrInfo.cpp
  EscalaFrameLowering.cpp
  EscalaMachineFunctionInfo.cpp
  EscalaRegisterInfo.cpp
  EscalaSubtarget.cpp
  EscalaTargetMachine.cpp
  EscalaSelectionDAGInfo.cpp
  EscalaAsmPrinter.cpp
  EscalaMCInstLower.cpp
  EscalaMachineScheduler.cpp
    EscalaVLIWPacketizer.cpp
  )

add_subdirectory(InstPrinter)
add_subdirectory(Disassembler)
add_subdirectory(TargetInfo)
add_subdirectory(MCTargetDesc)
add_subdirectory(AsmParser)

set(PLP_FILES EscalaSchedule.td.plp EscalaRegisterInfo.td.plp)
foreach (plp_file ${PLP_FILES})
  string(REPLACE ".plp" "" td_file ${plp_file})
  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${td_file}
    COMMAND plp ${plp_file}
    DEPENDS EscalaConstants.pm
  )
endforeach()
```

In other words I added a following piece:

```
set(PLP_FILES EscalaSchedule.td.plp EscalaRegisterInfo.td.plp)
foreach (plp_file ${PLP_FILES})
  string(REPLACE ".plp" "" td_file ${plp_file})
  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${td_file}
    COMMAND plp ${plp_file}
    DEPENDS EscalaConstants.pm
  )
```

For some reason I don't see any changes to my compilation. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

well, likely `${td_file}` specified as `OUTPUT` of `add_custom_command` is never referenced as a dependency for any target used to build `all` (default target). You may use [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_target.html) with `ALL` and `DEPENDS ${td_file}` options (name doesn't matter, use any unique identifier) *after* `add_custom_command` to chain building of required files into default target. Or, even better, accurately specify what parts of your project depend on files generated by the custom command(s). Use `add_dependencies` for that. if the generated file(s) are in turn the sources for some other build process (unlikely in your case, but nevertheless), then you should consider using `set_source_files_properties(${td_file} PROPERTIES GENERATED true)`.

Comment: I will test your suggestion tomorrow. But I also have another question. I want to add a custom command only if the tool, `plp`, is present in the `PATH`. If it is not present in the `PATH` then I would like to generate a warning message and continue with regular compilation. Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Sorry if this question seems obvious, I should have stated that I'm somewhat new to `cmake`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [find_program](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_program.html) is what you want for the task.